# Construct an event for a Lambda being called from AppSync

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-appsync

I want to call a lambda from the command line as if it were called from an AppSync GraphQL frontend.

How do I construct an event/payload such that it is roughly the same? And how do I shoot it at the lambda?

Comment: I tend to create a lambda that just says: `exports.handler = async(event)=>console.log("%j", event);` and then I assign that Lambda as the target for whatever service I want to integrate with. After that, go to the CloudWatch logs & copy out the event. You can then paste the event's JSON in your actual Lambda's "Test" tab within the AWS console to save it as a reusable test event.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to be able to construct this meaningfully without having to wire up AppSync to the Lambda (which in our case is something of a dog).